# How do you choose a suitable integration method?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, python, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to solve a system of 20 coupled differential equations through computing. These equations exhibit strong oscillatory solutions over millions of years. I have been reading around, however I can't find a general consensus on which integration methods to use for what, in particular I would like one that has a nice balance between computation time and accuracy.

So far I have been using a dynamic mix of (nonstiff) Adams method/ (stiff) BDF, this is very slow in Python with often inaccurate results over larger timescales.

Would Runge Kutta 4 be a better method for what I am trying to do? How can I generally pick a good method for what I am trying to do?

Comment: "over millions of years": this piece of information is of no use if we don't know the time scale. Compared to the age of the Universe, this is infinitesimal.

Comment: 10 million years with solutions at each 10 thousandth point

Comment: I don't think you understood my remark.

Comment: What other information is needed

Comment: What are the periods ?

Comment: Regardless of the integration method, the accumulation of floating point noise will contribute a term proportional to $\epsilon e^{LT}$ where $\epsilon$ is the precision of the number type, $L$ the Lipschitz constant of the system and $T$ the integration time. If $LT$ is not small, then you will need to use a multi-precision data type so that $\epsilon$ is small enough to compensate, which will considerably slow down your computation. So what is an estimate of $L$? Is such an estimate possible?

Comment: You should use python only to test the suitability of the methods over short time periods. For the long run you should use code in a compiled language.

Comment: You should try to see if the there exists an approximate analytic solution, e.g. when the couplings are set to zero, or if each variable only interacts with one other. Take e.g. the Solar system as an examples, where to first approximation we can ignore the interaction between the planets. Then the integration constants from the exact solution of the approximate system can be used to define a coordinate transform. We promote these integration constants as dynamic variables, with the approximate solution defining the transform.

Comment: The new variables then don't change rapidly anymore, allowing you to take large time steps in the numerical integration.